# Autostart processes and services

Tags: linux, shell

I want to control every single process my system use. (And learn what they do one by one)
I use openbox, but i'm confused about how to control startup programs and services.

I would like to have everything i need (minimum system) in a single place.
What is executed exactly ? In what order ?

```
"/etc/xdg/autostart/"
"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openbox-autostart"
".config/openbox/autostart.sh"
"/etc/init.d/"
"/etc/rc3.d/"
... ???
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check by using below mentioned commands.

```
ps - list the processes running on the system
kill - send a signal to one or more processes (usually to "kill" a process)
jobs - an alternate way of listing your own processes
bg - put a process in the background
fg - put a process in the forground
```